# If A and B are positive real numbers and each of the equations: $x^2+ax+2b=0$ and $x^2+2bx+a=0$ has real roots, what is the smallest value of A+B

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem**
In the equation:$x^2+ax+2b=0$ and $x^2+2bx+a=0$, we have to figure out the sum of a and b by using the following identity:
$P(x)=Q(x)*D(x)+R(x)$
where P(x) is the equations and q(x) is the quotient and d(x) is the divisor and r(x) is the remainder.

**My though process**
my initial stance was that because these two equations are both equal to zero, then they must equal each other so i set 
$x^2+ax+2b=x^2+2bx+a$
which *simplifies into:*
$ax+2b=2bx+a$
then i knew that that didn't go anywhere so then i set x=0 in the first equation and thought that B was zero but that can't be true
So then i assigned R and S as the roots to the equations where i figured that in general given a simple quadratic equation: $ax^2+bx+c$ with the roots r and s, $r+s=\frac{-b}{a}$ and $rs=\frac{c}{a}$

and going back to the real equation we can set 
$r+s=\frac{-a}{1}$ in the equation $x^2+ax+2b=0$ and $rs=\frac{2b}{1}$

and with the same thing to the other equation I got:
$r+s=\frac{-2b}{1}$ and $rs=\frac{a}{1}$

as stated these two equation can be set equal to each other because they are both equal to 0.
This means that $\frac{-a}{1}$=$\frac{-2b}{1}$
and $\frac{2b}{1}$=$\frac{a}{1}$
and thats where i got stuck.

Comment: Please look at your title, $A , B ??$

Comment: I can't see the correlation of **real roots** and **division algorithm**.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki yes a+b because we want to find out the sum of a and b, not to find the exact coefficients, if you can find the exact values of a and b that would also be great too

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We need discriminant $\ge0,$

$\implies a^2\ge8b, 4b^2\ge4a\iff b^2\ge a$

$a^4\ge64a\iff a(a-4)(a^2+4a+4^2)\ge0\iff a(a-4)\ge0$ as $a^2+4a+4^2=(a+2)^2+2^2\ge2^2>0$

$\implies$ either $a\le0$ or $a-4\ge0\iff a\ge4$

But $a$ is positive.

Comment: can you explain how u got $a^4 \ge 64a?$ along with the other claims